# Error in updating final FC layer for fine tuning AlexNet

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

Hello I have recently started working on fine tuning the Alexnet model for my own dataset.

I want to modify the final two layer as I have only two classes:

```
net.layers = net.layers(1:end-2);
```

But when I modify the final FC layer like that and it gives me error.

```
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv',...
'weights', {{f*randn(1,1,4196,2, 'single'), zeros(1,2,'single')}},...
'stride', [1 1],...
'pad', [0 0 0 0]) ;
Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.
```

Anyone, please help me resolve the error

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your net is a DagNN. You can't add layer like a simplenn. You can either modify the weight matrix in the corresponding net.param(.) of net.layer(end) (assuming net.layer(end) is the final FC) or remove the last layer and add a new one yourself using the helper functions (i.e., removeLayer and addLayer) provided in the @DagNN folder. Note that removeLayer and addLayer are private functions of class DagNN.